# Cannot Create New File From Root Folder in Brackets

Tags: adobe-brackets

I am using Brackets Release 1.4 and have a question.  I cannot figure out how to "Add a new file"  to the top level (root) folder.  It will allow me to add new files to sub folders.  A lot of tutorials that use Brackets tell you to 'Add' a new file in the root folder, but I cannot get Brackets to do this.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Windows, you can for example use the Command Prompt, cd into your root folder and then create the file with the touch command.

Here are some basic terminal commands:
http://masteruby.github.io/productivity-booster/2014/03/26/top-ten-commands-in-terminal-you-will-use-everyday.html

Or you could go to file -> New... and then, save as... to save the file in the folder of your liking.

Comment: Thank You I will try the suggestions.